# C# html5 web browser object

Tags: c#, html

I am attempting to make a web browser object in C# which support html5 as good as Safari or Chrome. My main goal is for playing video, or supporting the video tag. So far i have got WebKit.Net working and playing html5 video off w3schools website, but this only works when quicktime is installed; and i really hate that route. I read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video so i know somewhat why quick time is needed.

I am currently attempting to wrap up chromium into a C# web browser object. Do you have any suggestions on how i can accomplish creating a C# Web Browser which support html5?

Comment: Is there anything you are trying to accomplish that isn't already implemented in http://sourceforge.net/projects/webkitdotnet/?

Answer (score 1):

You could also check out my new project: https://github.com/chillitom/CefSharp

This brings the Chromium Embedded Framework to .Net / C#.  See the Github page for source, binaries and example.

Some features:

- a browser control with navigation commands
- INotifyPropertyChanged events
- ExecuteJavascript
- Register your own scheme/protocol handlers
- intercept resource downloads
- bind CLR objects into Chromium's JavaScript context.

It's still in the pre-alpha stages so all feedback appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using WPF, you can use http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2009/08/25/a-real-wpf-webbrowser/. This is a Chromium implementation for WPF.